# Beginner learning sql joins in mySQL

Tags: sql

I have created 3 tables: dog, customer and owner. It is a many to one relationship with many dogs owned by 1 customer.

```
CREATE TABLE dog
(
DogID int(6) NOT NULL,
DogName varchar(15),
medicalID int (6),
Gender character(1) check(gender in ('m', 'f')),
Age int(2),
Breed varchar(15),
size character (1) check(size in ('s', 'm', 'l')),
primary key (DogID));

CREATE TABLE Owns
(
DogID int (6)primary key,
CustomerID int (6),
foreign key (CustomerID) references customer (CustomerID),
foreign key (DogID) references dog (DogID));

CREATE TABLE customer
(
CustomerID int(6) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(15),
Surname varchar(15),
Address varchar(225),
email varchar (30), 
TelNo varchar (15),
MobNo Varchar (15), 
EmergencyName varchar (40), 
EmergencyPhoneNo varchar(15),
primary key (CustomerID));
```

I have queried with but nothing is returned.

```
select dog.dogName 
from dog, owns, customer
where owns.dogID = dog.dogId
  and customer.customerID = owns.customerID
  and customer.FirstName = "CustomersName";
```

Comment: (1) Then you have no data that satisfies the conditions of the query.  Try setting up a SQL Fiddle.  (2) *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: which join actually u want to do ? inner join or something else

Comment: Which SQL you are using? SQL Server or MySQL or else?

Answer (score 0):

You created the tables, now you need to `INSERT` the data.

```
INSERT INTO dog(<fields>) VALUES(<values>);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully created the tables the next step is to put some data in them. Otherwise you won't get anything back from your query. You need to insert a record into the dog and customer tables and associate them via the owns table. After performing those 3 inserts you should be able to join on their keys and query for data.

For example:

```
insert into dog(DogID, DogName, medicalID, Gender, Age, Breed, Size) values ('111111', 'Spike', '111111', '12', 'Wolf', 'l' );

insert into customer ( CustomerID, FirstName, Surname, Address, email, TelNo, MobNo, EmergencyName, EmergencyPhoneNo ) values ( '222222', 'Abe', 'Lincoln', '123 Street', 'blah@blah.com', '8675309', '8675309', 'Bob', '8675309' );    

insert into owns ( DogID, CustomerID ) values ( '111111', '222222' );

select DogName from dog as d
join owns as o on o.DogID = d.DogID
join customer as c on c.CustomerId = o.CustomerID
where c.FirstName = 'Abe';
```

Note that your syntax may be slightly different. I've been using Oracle for a while.